# Ignore dependency of a dependency in python setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I maintain a package A that depends on a package B and a package C, both of which are in my requirements.txt file. The dependency is installed in setup.py by being passed through install_requires in setup.py. Package B however also depends on package C, but requires it to be a very specific older version. My package A however requires package C to be a more recent version or newer. When running setup.py, how can I ask the version dependency enforced by Package B to be ignored?

Comment: If package B requires C to be a very specific older version may be its authors have a reason? What if A forces C to be a newer version and that would make B to behave badly?

Comment: What if I'm fairly certain it won't affect their package? What are my options?

Comment: Ask the authors of B to upgrade dependency C. Or fork B, upgrade C yourself and use your fork as a dependency in A. Generally `pip` is not very fond of contradicting dependencies.